# getting answer body and question body in same request

Tags: support, api, answers, filter

I'm trying to get only questions and answers.

I [filtered](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!*NZtzqX.Z9oQQ3LrjTC2IsTsXkBn)Arn&site=judaism&run=true%22)  the fields, to get also the body of answers, but I don't get an answers JSON object.

What am I missing?

I know about [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/4213/get-questions-with-body-and-answers), but I don't want to bring many fields, please help me find the field I'm missing.

Comment: Slightly related: https://stackapps.com/questions/4213/get-questions-with-body-and-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognize that problem, I've had it too in the past. It may be a bit counterintuitive, but you also have to select `question.answers` in the filter.

[image]

A possible reason for this to not be automatic is that if you want comment details of the question only, you might want `question.comments` autoselected, but not `question.answers` and `answer.comments`. That's why you have to select it explicitly.